Software UART handled in interrupt mode makes my data corrupted
I'm currently working on getting my barcode scanner to work using soft-uart library by liyanboy74 on STM32 NUCLEOF446RE.
First of all when falling edge on my GPIO pin is detected, GPIO_EXTI_Callback() function is called which enables softuart and calls HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT() on timer3 configured as described on GitHub library.
void HAL_GPIO_EXTI_Callback(uint16_t GPIO_Pin) {
  if (GPIO_Pin == GPIO_PIN_13) {
    SoftUartEnableRx(0);
    HAL_TIM_Base_Start_IT(&htim3);
  }
}

Then after period elapsed, this callback is called.
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim) {
  if (htim == &htim3) {
    SoftUartHandler();
    if (!SUart[0].RxTimingFlag && SUart[0].RxBitCounter == 0) {
      HAL_TIM_Base_Stop_IT(htim);
      SoftUartDisableRx(0);
      printData();
    }
  }
}

I wrote printData function which is supposed to print every digit of the barcode but currently only first digit appears in my RealTerm. I'm puzzled what went wrong, with polling everything was fine.
void printData(void) {
  uint8_t ch;
  uint8_t buffer[100];
  uint8_t bufferIndex = 0;

  ch = getChar(0); // taken from GitHub library
  HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, &ch, 1, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
  if (ch == '\r') {
    buffer[bufferIndex++] = '\r';
    buffer[bufferIndex++] = '\n';
    HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buffer, bufferIndex, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
    bufferIndex = 0;
  } else {
    buffer[bufferIndex++] = ch;
    if (bufferIndex >= sizeof(buffer)) {
      HAL_UART_Transmit(&huart2, buffer, bufferIndex, HAL_MAX_DELAY);
      bufferIndex = 0;
    }
  }
}

Example 3 from the library shows how to implement it as polling and it works just fine and I wonder what went wrong. I'm guessing that it is timings issue but im not sure.
I'm fully aware that the chip I'm using has plenty of hardware UARTs because I'm using all of them. I'm creating 360 degree barcode scanner and to cover 360 degrees I'm using 6 scanning engines (each of them has been connected to separate UART but USART2 is handling communication with PC to display barcodes & process them further) so I'm left with 5 hardware UARTS and 6 scanning engines. That's the reason behind using softuart. I have set the baud rate to 9600 as it's default for my scanning engines.

This chip has loads of real UARTs, what is the reason for bit-banging it with a GPIO?  Also what is the baud rate?  it had better be set really low with big gaps in between each byte in order to have time for you to print out on another UART in between each received byte.

Why did you "escape" the square brackets in the code?

Did you check if  the "if" condition is still true? And since you're printing out char by char I don't understand your printData function. No need for buffers: just send on the pc uart the received byte (and append a lf if a cr is received)
